# PostgreSQL - Do I need the command-line tool?

Tags: postgresql, shell

I decided to give PostgreSQL a try. It looks really interesting, but it isn't very user friendly at all.

I got some great help from the PostgreSQL e-mail list, but they insist that the tool to use is the command-line editor (PSQL). Unfortunately, it's a total disaster. When I open it, it opens at least two instances, which soon multiply into a dozen. It also seems to somehow hijack my Apple terminal on my Mac. I can type the same command into two different terminal boxes and get two different results. I don't have a clue what's going on.

Anyway, to get to the point, PostgreSQL is obviously over my head. There's a local PostgreSQL users group that meets once a month - at night, when I'm working. But I'd like to try and make the very beginning of their next meeting and drop them a note. I'd like to hire someone to help me get PostgreSQL set up on my laptop and online, fix whatever the problem is and show me how to create a database and table.

Actually, I've already created a database and table, which I can access with pgAdmin III. But I can't see them with the shell/ terminal. So that's my question: If I can hire someone to get PostgreSQL up and running, will I be able to work with it using pgAdmin III or some other tool, or am I going to be chained to the shell (PSGL)?

If the shell/terminal is indispensable, then I think I'm going to abandon it. It looks like a great program, but I just don't have time to jump through all the hoops right now.

Comment: "It opens at least two instances, maybe a dozen" .. Huh? How do you do that? (do you finish them by control-z? : dont!)

Comment: BTW: You dont need to stay inside psql; can use your favourite editor to prepare the sql and submit it by `psql -U username -d databasename -f your_script_file`

Comment: I don't have a clue what's going on. When I click on the PostgreSQL on the dock, it opens an another terminal icon that looks different; it appears to Apple's terminal. At the same time it opens at least two instances. If I type or past in some text and hit enter, it apparently opens another window. I haven't hit control-z. All I've been doing is typing or pasting text and hitting enter.

Comment: So basically, you are new to the command line, and Apple isn't very cooperative. Don't they have plain ordinary terminal windows ("shells") with just one command prompt in it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. All I want to know is whether or not the command-line tool is necessary. If I can't get by without it, then I want nothing to do with PostgreSQL. The community is very helpful, but I've also discovered that they're very geeky - lots of anti-Mac comments. It sounds like PostgreSQL works best in a Linux/Microsoft environment, which would be another reason for me to drop it.

Comment: Postgres is basically unix-based. (linux and Apple/OSX are both unix variants) The front-ends, (such as psql or pgadmin) should work on any platform. pgadmin has a GUI, but you still have to type in the SQL commands into some text window and submit it (with F5, IIRC)

Comment: It sounds like you're saying YES, you can't do PostgreSQL without the command-line tool. Unfortunately, that's a deal killer for me. I was hoping pgAdmin III would be something like phpMyAdmin. PostgreSQL's shell, terminal or whatever you want to call it is simply bizarre. I'll stick with MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom You know most of the PostgreSQL core developers use Macs, right? I don't know where you're getting the idea it's anti-mac. There are some issues with how Apple packaged PostgreSQL in Mac OS X, but they fixed those.

Comment: I was judging by 1) the bizarre problems I'm having with it on my Mac and 2) the anti-Mac comments people started making on the e-mail list. It began to sound like a Microsoft/Linux fan club. I figured I'd give it one more chance and try to hire someone to set it up for me. But if I'm going to be forever chained to screwy command-line tool, then it just isn't worth it.

Comment: The command line is not *required*. There are many different GUI tools to connect to Postgres and run SQL statements. A list of those tools is available in the Postgres wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `psql` to use PostgreSQL. Many experienced users prefer it, but you can use nothing but PgAdmin and get by just fine. That's what a great many users do.

PostgreSQL is fine on Mac OS X. A number of core developers use Mac OS X and do their development on it. Much like many MySQL users use phpmyadmin, etc, and never use the `mysql` command line tool.

There were some packaging issues on OS X related to Apple's bundling of PostgreSQL but those are resolved in more recent versions of OS X.

There are also some challenges with different packages of PostgreSQL on OS X - EnterpriseDB, Macports, Homebrew, etc. But those are mostly a matter of documentation and user misunderstanding; each package is in its self just fine. Similar issues exist on Linux, where OS packages, PGDG packages, and EDB's packages can tread on each others' toes.

Characterising the PostgreSQL community as a "Microsoft/Linux fan club" is hilarious, by the way. Windows is tolerated at best by most of the core devs and users on the mailing list.

It's really hard to tell what problem you're encountering based on the description given. Maybe you have multiple different PostgreSQL packages installed, so you have more than one server instance, and are getting them confused? Similarly, I can't tell what's going on with the `psql` terminal link in the dock. I'd ignore it and use `psql` from the usual Apple `Terminal.app` if you want to use `psql`. Otherwise just use PgAdmin.

One area where you will run into trouble is that because most experienced users use `psql`, if you ask questions specific to PgAdmin or other tools, rather than PostgreSQL its self, people will pretty much shrug their shoulders and say "dunno, but you do it like  in `psql`". I haven't used PgAdmin for my own stuff in years, and have to go hunting around in the manual if I want to figure out how to do something so I can explain it to somebody. Moreso with things like Navicat, which I've never used at all. The people who use those tools are *usually not the ones spending their time helping other people out*, so you get help from experienced and enthusiastic users who're also the ones most likely to use the expert-oriented tools.

Relevant link: http://phili.pe/posts/postgresql-on-the-command-line/

Comment: Wow, thanks for that answer! I must have just run into a group of hard core techies. I've spent the last few hours wrestling with the terminal, and they refused to help me figure out how to do anything with pgAdmin. Anyway, maybe I should post my PostgreSQL questions here, rather than on the list. ;)

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Heh. I *am* a hard-core techie. I'm just trying to be patient. Honestly, the way you write *will* rub people the wrong way, and get you much less helpful responses than you are hoping for. You're approaching this in a way that'll make people irritable and defensive. If you lighten up on the hyperbole - "total disaster", "chained to the shell", etc - it will help. You're broadcasting your expectation that things work a particular way, and your unwillingness to explore other options. That doesn't usually make people keen to help. I know from experience, as I used to do it myself.

Comment: I don't mean "geek" as an insult. I define geeks as people who know a lot about computers and software - which is a plus. The negative is that they frequently don't have a lot of patience with newbies or people who prefer GUI's. I'm a writer first, a software programmer second. I don't have time to jump through endless hoops and always go for a user-friendly solution. That's why I dropped M$ in favor of a Mac. ;)

Comment: If you're looking for simple and easy, Microsoft Access might be a better option. Or FileMaker, TapForms, iDatabase, etc. These tools integrate user interface and form building with the database engine, providing a seamless single-package setup. PostgreSQL is first and foremost a *developer tool*, a database *engine* you can use to build and run applications with, and is not intended to be an end user product. It's very powerful, but without overlaying 3rd party tools it's not something you can usefully use directly. You talk to it through scripts/programs.

Comment: I was thinking of using MySQL and PostgreSQL side by side, using the latter primarily for recursion/hierarchical stuff. When I get up to speed, then I can consider dumping MySQL in favor of PostgreSQL. But if the command-line tool isn't working, and the community doesn't want to offer advice regarding pgAdmin, then it might be pointless. However, I'm still thinking of hiring someone to set it up correctly and fix whatever's wrong.

Comment: If you're not a fan of complicated, then using two database management systems is probably not a good way to achieve that ;) . If you have a specific issue with the tools, consider posting a new question with specifics. Error messages, screenshots, explanations of what you've done/tried, what you installed from where, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using DBeaver to write and execute my Postgres queries because I don't like neither psql nor PgAdmin. Not that DBeaver is without its faults but at least it has decent code completion and an easy way to switch databases / schemas. In the end it's also about what you're used to and I guess coming form SQL Server with Management Studio I found this an easier way in into Postgres.

It's true that in most Postgres books psql is the standard but I usually try to convert the psql specific code to queries I can run in DBeaver, which is usually an interesting (although somewhat frustrating at times) exercise...